# Carregar arquivo *.pdf em uma página JSP

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, navegador-de-internet

Consegui abrir uma página de um arquivo *.pdf no Acrobat pelo java a partir deste código:

```
try {

        File pdfFile = new File("C:\\testes\\teste.pdf");
        if (pdfFile.exists()) {
            String cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader DC\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
            String param1 = "/A";
            String param2 = "page=2";

            String[] cmds = new String[]{cmd, param1, param2, pdfFile.getAbsolutePath()};
            Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmds).start();
            /*if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                //Desktop.getDesktop().open(pdfFile);

            } else {
                System.out.println("Awt Desktop não disponível");
            }*/

        } else {
            System.out.println("Ficheiro inexistente");
        }

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

É possível fazer o mesmo pelo browser com JSP?

Comment: <a href = 'enderecoArquivo'>Clique aqui<\a>?

Comment: A questão é que eu precise que ele abra automaticamente o PDF da pasta sem um botão